# Node.js set wrong content length. how do i set this one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I need some help. Even I set content-length to response object, it seems doesn't work. Did I something wrong?

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': res._data.ContentType,
  'Content-Length': res._data.ContentLength,
  ETag: res._data.ETag
});
res.send(res._data.Body);
```

I use express and body-parser to send data, and I set Content-Length.

```
res.header('Content-Type', res._data.ContentType);
res.header('content-length', res._data.ContentLength);
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

I tried this one too.

```
{ AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 'Thu, 15 Jan 2015 22:23:43 GMT',
  ContentLength: '648789',
  ETag: '"7da971554e6ff4f6dfcdb7b2ba5e0be3"',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0a 0c 14 0d 0c 0b 0b 0c 19 12 13 0f 14 ...> }
```

This is result of `console.log(res._data)`. As you see I set content-length.

```
GET /api/images/54b83dec5e7d97c546e0c41a 200 584.524 ms - 1227943
```

But node.js response wrong content-length to client as size 1227943.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
content-length:1227943
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Thu, 15 Jan 2015 23:37:52 GMT
ETag:"7da971554e6ff4f6dfcdb7b2ba5e0be3"
X-Powered-By:Express
```

And client receive too. Someone knows what I missed?
Please help me.

Oh I forgot to mentioned it. When I use Postman(chrome extension) to get data, It works fine.

```
GET /api/images/54b83dec5e7d97c546e0c41a 200 664.427 ms - 648789
```

So really I don't know why it happened.

Comment: `res._data` is what I want to response to client, in this case that data from AWS S3 object. And `res.end()` also try to put, but alway response wrong content-length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manually set `Content-Length` when you use Express' `response.send` method: one of the last things that method does is set `Content-Length` based on (surprise) the length of the content being sent.  You can see that at the end of the `send` method in the source code:

https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.11/lib/response.js

In other words, Express is overriding `Content-Length`.

It looks like `res._data.ContentLength` doesn't reflect the size of the buffer `res._data.Body`.  Check to see what `res._data.Body.length` is; I'm guessing it's 1227943.

Comment: Thank's to your answer. I tried set `content-length` because I received wrong `content-length` when I receive data in chrome.

Comment: Updated.  I think your problem is in `res._data`.  What is setting `res._data`?  I don't think `res._data.ContentLength` is what you think it is....

Comment: `res._data` is response data of AWS S3 object. In this object, `Body` is Buffered data what I want to return it. And `ContentLength` is that `Body` buffer's length. Almost case it works fine. But when it response little bit a large data(in chrome), it response wrong length. And when I use Postman, it works ok too.

Comment: Hm...I can't help but think that this is a content encoding problem...perhaps it's being encoded as UTF-8?  The size you're getting is almost twice the reported buffer size, which could be consistent with unwanted UTF-8 encoding....  Postman is probably setting the Accept header....  I would examine all of the headers coming and going and see if there are any clues....

Comment: Thank you. I try to use `toString()` on response data, it return wrong number of `content-length` even I tried on Postman. I see now encoding problem. Thank you Ethan. (Also I tried print log `content-length` in `response.js` what you linked it. And it returned correct length.) Anyway solve the problem. Thanks!